Meta tags: [scope], [allowed-questions] and [closed-questions]
While tagging this question, I noticed that we have scope, allowed-questions and closed-questions.  Should they just be merged?

Tagging on the per-site metas is now a bit of a mess, see this question on Meta Stack Overflow: Proposing tag wiki creation does not work on meta sites. I'll see if we can merge some of those tags, even if we don't get tag wikis.

After two days of no feedback by the community at all, and a confirmation by my co-moderator Ninefingers, I merged scope into allowed-questions - these mean as much as "What is on-topic on Crypto.SE?".
closed-questions is a bit different, it means "Why was this question closed?".
(As long as there are no tag-wikis for meta tags, I'll let this post here be the "definition" of these tags, making it community-wiki to allow editing. Feel free to post a separate question and provide an answer for all tags, though.)
